# chrome extension to run even when the pop-up is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am coding a Timer on a chrome extension with javascript. Everything works when the popup is opened but when the popup closes everything resets. Is there a way to keep the timer running even when the popup is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Background Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages):

> A background page is loaded when it is needed, and unloaded when it
>   goes idle.